# Passing java.sql.date to netezza jdbc driver

Tags: jdbc, netezza

When passing a Java.Sql.Date as a bind variable (a question mark in my query text) in a PreparedStatement to nzjdbc.jar, I'm getting:

pg_atoi: error in "2010-02-01": can't parse "-02-01"

what gives? I thought that the whole purpose of a JDBC driver is to fix such issues :(

Comment: I can now narrow it down. The problem only reproduces when the SQL is in this form:

``select * from baa 
where start_date <= ? - 30``

and does not reproduce when you remove the "- 30". 
My guess: when you specify the - 30, Netezza is trying to parse the bind variable as something other than date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, found the answer, not related to JDBC.

When passing a date variable to JDBC, all it does is translate it to a literal string fitting the Netezza dateStyle, e.g. '2011-11-06 00:00:00'. It does not wrap it with a cast or to_date or anything.

However, when you try `select '2011-11-06 00:00:00' - 30` from any Netezza client, you get a pg-atoi parse error, as Netezza tries to parse the string as a number, **not** as a date.

Solution: `select cast('2004-02-22 00:00:00.000' as date) - 30 as bla;`

its all cosmic love baby.

Comment: it baffles me that Netezza jdbc driver converts dates to string before sending it to database...